# Django-filter 2 use @property to filter?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I've got this filter:

```
class SchoolFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = {
            'name': ['icontains'],
            'special_id': ['icontains'],
        }
```

Where `special_id` is a @property of the School Model:

```
@property
    def special_id(self):
        type = self.type
        unique_id = self.unique_id
        code = self.code
        if unique_id < 10:
            unique_id = f'0{unique_id}'
        if int(self.code) < 10:
            code = f'0{self.code}'
        special_id = f'{code}{type}{id}'
        return special_id
```

I've tried to google some answers, but couldn't find anything. Right now If I use my filter like I do I only receive this error:

`'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: special_id`

How could I define the property as a field for this FilterSet? Is it even possible for me to use django-filter with a @property?

Thanks for any answer!

**Update:**

Figured it out. Not the prettiest solution, but ayyy

```
class SchoolFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    special_id = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="special_id", method="special_id_filter", label="Special School ID")

    def special_id_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        schools_pk = []
        for obj in queryset:
            if obj.special_id == value:
                schools_pk.append(obj.pk)
        queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=schools_pk)
        return queryset

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = {
            'name': ['icontains'],
            'special_id': ['icontains'],
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. FilterSet will only filter on actual fields, since FilterSet alters a QuerySet.

QuerySets do a database call based on the filters applied, which means you can only filter on fields actually stored in the database.

You could annotate your QuerySet to add the special_id, but an annotation like this is pretty complex to chain together.

A better way to do this would be to create a custom filter on your FilterSet, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. If you can explain what special_id is, and exactly why you want to search it through icontains, then I could maybe point you in the right direction.

[This is an implementation of a MethodFilter, which I think is similar what you want.](https://gist.github.com/jpadilla/809f400c1217ae3e37b6)

Comment: I think the custom filter would be my best choice. The `special_id` is basically a "ID" build together by other fields from the model: code, type and unique_id.

So for example a school has the code "A", a type of "PS" (Preschool) and a unique_id of "3", so the special id would be: APS3 and my customer should be able to search just for that special_id when viewing the table. I know it would be a lot easier if the special_id would be a field itself, but the special_id is being build automatically when a school is created and it has to be created by those 3 fields

Comment: Well I managed to do it by using a custom MethodFilter, its not the prettiest solution, but it works I guess. If someone maybe knows an even cleaner solution I'd be happy, but for now I would say that thanks to your link I figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

`FilterSet` operates by filtering queryset (adding where conditions to the underlying sql). Which means, `FilterSet` can operate only on `Columns` that are present in the database. Here the `special_id` is a computed property (It is not a column, it is calculated on the fly using other fields/columns), So it wont work.

The work around is to make `special_id` a normal field/column, compute the value at runtime and write to database at the time of save.